# How to convert Json inside jsonList into Dart model?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I have been trying to convert JSON to Dart using Code generation. I want to assign List into the messages variable but I'm not able to make this done.

How is it possible to convert the messages into **MessagesModel** in the user class?

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'user.freezed.dart';
part 'user.g.dart';

@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User({
    required int id,
    required String name,
    required String? profilePic,
    required List<Messages>? messages, //error: [Instance of 'Messages', Instance of 'Messages']
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}


class Messages {
  Messages({
    required this.isSend,
    required this.time,
    required this.text,
  });
  late final bool isSend;
  late final String time;
  late final String text;
  
  Messages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    isSend = json['is_send'];
    time = json['time'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['is_send'] = isSend;
    _data['time'] = time;
    _data['text'] = text;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Sample input:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John Dio",
    "profilePic":
        "https://dummy-profile.png",
    "messages": [
      {
        "isSend": true,
        "time": "12:05 AM",
        "text": "Hi My friend this is a sample text message of type send"
      },
      {
        "isSend": false,
        "time": "12:05 AM",
        "text": "hehe im rplyin to you buddy hehe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Log result of the user:

```
User(id: 0, name: John Dio, profilePic: https://dummy-profile.png, messages: [Instance of 'Messages', Instance of 'Messages'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in build.yaml

```html
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          explicit_to_json: true
```

or

```html
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'user.freezed.dart';
part 'user.g.dart';

@freezed
class User with _$User {
JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)//specify it here
  const factory User({
    required int id,
    required String name,
    required String? profilePic,
    required List<Messages>? messages, //error: [Instance of 'Messages', Instance of 'Messages']
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}


class Messages {
  Messages({
    required this.isSend,
    required this.time,
    required this.text,
  });
  late final bool isSend;
  late final String time;
  late final String text;
  
  Messages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    isSend = json['is_send'];
    time = json['time'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['is_send'] = isSend;
    _data['time'] = time;
    _data['text'] = text;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialize nested lists of freezed objects, you must specify:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
```

or you can also specify so in in your  `build.yaml` file. Note that you must trigger code generation again.
Check the notes at: https://pub.dev/packages/freezed